# Sending Goods and Bank Transfer Scam?

Tags: scams, money-transfer, shipping

I have an online clothes webshop on Aliexpress.
Recently I have been approached by a buyer on Aliexpress who only wants to buy the goods directly and through (international) Bank Transfer.
The buyer claims he will do a bank transfer to me and that I can send the goods afterwards. He only needs a proof of payment from me.

Now I have read a lot about scams on this website and I start being worried. Is there a way that she can do a bank transfer and then cancel the transfer after I have sent the goods?
If this is a kind of Scam, how do I make sure this is a real deal?

This buyer also looks legit on Aliexpress (diamond buyer)

Comment: Yes, she can cancel it. Yes, it's 100% scam.

Comment: What does "buy the goods **directly**" mean? How do you normally sell goods?

Comment: You have a shop on Aliexpress, the buyer is a diamond buyer on Aliexpress. You both have a good relationship with Aliexpress already. What is the benefit to YOU to use a bank transfer instead of Aliexpress? Do you save on fees? What is the benefit to the buyer to do a side-deal? Does he avoid fees? Why would a buyer go around Aliexpress and their stated protection policy https://www.aliexpress.com/buyerprotection/overview.html ? If there is no obvious benefit to the buyer to go around Aliexpress then what he is trying to do is set you up for a scam or theft.

Comment: Also, be aware that processing payment outside of Aliexpress means Aliexpress will not be available to help you settle any disputes.  Even if it's *not* a scam, things can go wrong.  Are you willing to take that potential headache on yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could very well be a scam, so you should be careful.

Some transfers are reversible, other's are not. You should talk to your bank: they should be able to tell you what types of transfer you should be using and how you can know when the money is truly yours.

Comment: And be sure they understand you are asking when the money is irreversible -- NOT when you can withdraw or spend it. Those are NOT the same, and the latter is what most customers care about and the bank people are used to answering. You might be allowed to withdraw after 1-3 days, but it can be reversed 30 days later (sometimes even 90 days or more) and then you are required to pay it back.